# ng-grid FOUC artefacts

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I started using ng-grid, and honestly seems it's not easy to tame that beast. I'm having various problems and this is one of them. I'm using ui-router and before ng-grid I was using my own implementation based on ng-repeat and haven't encountered this, so I'm assuming somehow ng-grid is responsible.

So I have a few tabs and ui-view with a grid underneath. Everytime you switch a tab, controller initiates a request and fetches data for the grid. Very first time when you open the app, everything seems to be fine, but whenever you switch to a different tab, for a few milliseconds it shows ugly, unbound content.

I tried to hide grid with ng-if, ng-hide and ng-show - (data.length <= 0), but that didn't work. I tried to place a few $timeout functions, that didn't help either.

Any ideas how to fix that?

UPD: first time when I posted this question I thought what if I make the grid transparent and then change opacity after it gets the data. So it kinda did the trick.

```
jQuery.animate({opacity:1})
```

and then I deleted the question, but soon I realized this is not very good way to solve the problem - not very anguleresque. Question remains open.

UPD: Had to abandon ng-grid and currently looking for something better. ng-grid in its current state is horrible. It's painfully slow, full of strange bugs and pretty much useless. Version 3 if far from being ready, and current version is abandoned. Very, very sad.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the version of ng-grid you are using? We have a similar problem where page template tags are being shown on slower browsers.

Comment: v2.0.12 * Compiled At: 08/04/2014 16:09

Comment: If you see some weird artefacts when tab-switching, doesn't it mean your data array isn't empty ? You should make sure to dump it on each request `$scope.data = [];` (or something similar). ng-hide or ng-cloak should work then.

Answer (score 1):

Actually after using ng-grid for awhile, I have to admit - it's really, really bad. Anyone who values own time and nerves should stay away from it. In its current state project is completely broken, have tons of bugs and authors won't even accept any tickets. They all working hard on a new version and honestly God knows when they ship it. So, for your own sake DON'T use it! I mean I believe in this product and that team. After all those guys gave us awesome ui-router and amazing angular-ui directives. Check the date, who knows maybe this answer already is obsolte and by the time you run across this post all the problems in ng-grid are already solved. But simple fact still remains - the product was so bad, they even decided to rename it.

For now I switched to [ux-angularjs-datagrid](https://github.com/webux/ux-angularjs-datagrid). It may not be a complete grid solution and doesn't have a cool name and many features you're gonna have to build yourself, but it's amazingly fast and responsive.